# Standard ML string to a list

Tags: string, list, standards, sml, ml

Is there a way in ML to take in a string and output a list of those string where a separation is a space, newline or eof, but also keeping strings inside strings intact?

EX) hello world "my id" is 5555

-> [hello, world, my id, is, 5555]

I am working on a tokenizing these then into:

->[word, word, string, word, int]

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can! Here's the idea:

If we take a string like `"Hello World, \"my id\" is 5555"`, we can split it at the quote marks, ignoring the spaces for now. This gives us `["Hello World, ", "my id", " is 5555"]`. The important thing to notice here is that the list contains three elements - an odd number. As long as the string only contains pairs of quotes (as it will if it's properly formatted), we'll always get an odd number of elements when we split at the quote marks.

A second important thing is that all the even-numbered elements of the list will be strings that were unquoted (if we start counting from 0), and the odd-numbered ones were quoted. That means that all we need to do is tokenize the ones that were unquoted, and then we're done!

I put some code together - you can continue from there:

```
fun foo s =
let
  val quoteSep = String.tokens (fn c => c = #"\"") s

  val spaceSep = String.tokens (fn c => c = #" ") (* change this to include newlines and stuff *)

  fun sepEven []  = []
    | sepEven [x] = (* there were no quotes in the string *)
    | sepEven (x::y::xs) = (* x was unquoted, y was quoted *)
in
  if length quoteSep mod 2 = 0
  then (* there was an uneven number of quote marks - something is wrong! *)
  else (* call sepEven *)
end
```

Comment: What if the strings contain escaped quotes? Can still do that, but at that point I think a little hand-written scanner is simpler (and more efficient).

Comment: Doubly-escaped quotes? Like `\\\"`? Yes, then I think a scanner is a better solution. I don't *think* that was part of OP's problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

[`String.tokens`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/string.html#SIG%3aSTRING.tokens%3aVAL) brings you halfway there. But if you really want to handle quotes like you are sketching then there is no way around writing an actual lexer. [MLlex](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/ML-Lex/manual.html), which comes with SML/NJ and MLton (but is usable with any SML) could help. Or you just write it by hand, which should be easy enough in this case as well.